# unable to run service using unix socket or app.sock file is not getting created

Tags: python, flask

I have hardware servie, which needs to be run as a service. If I run sudo harware_servicee.py directly is it working as expected, But if I try same thing as a service then app.sock file is not getting created.

Given the example scenario below.

hardware_service.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/overall")
def overall_stats_route():
    data = {
        "os": get_os_info(),
        "cpu": get_cpu_info(),
        "disk": get_disk_info(),
        "swap": get_swap_info(),
        "disk_partitions": get_partitions_info(),
    }
    return jsonify(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Running as service...")
    app.run(host="unix://usr/bin/app.sock")
```

cd /etc/systemd/system
hardware_service.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/<user>/hardware_service.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start hardware_service

sudo systemctl status hardware_service

sudo systemctl enable hardware_service
```

If i run this as service(hardwaare_service) app.sock is not getting created under /usr/bin. but if run sudo python hardware_service.py then app.sock file is getting created.

sudo systemctl status hardware_service

```
`● hardware_service.service - My Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hardware_service.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-02-23 09:39:51 UTC; 21h ago
 Main PID: 22559 (hardware_servic)
   CGroup: /system.slice/hardware_service.service
           ├─22559 /home/narenautod/dist/hardware_service
           └─22560 /home/narenautod/dist/hardware_service

Feb 23 09:39:51 narenautod systemd[1]: Started My Service.
Feb 23 09:39:51 narenautod hardware_service[22559]: Running as service...
Feb 23 09:39:51 narenautod hardware_service[22559]: * Serving Flask app "hardware_service" (lazy loading)
Feb 23 09:39:51 narenautod hardware_service[22559]: * Environment: production
Feb 23 09:39:51 narenautod hardware_service[22559]: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Feb 23 09:39:51 narenautod hardware_service[22559]: Use a production WSGI server instead.
Feb 23 09:39:51 narenautod hardware_service[22559]: * Debug mode: off
Feb 23 09:39:51 narenautod hardware_service[22559]: * Running on unix:////app.sock (Press CTRL+C to quit)`
```

Feb 23 11:01:49 narenautod systemd[1]: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.

client.py

```
`import requests_unixsocket

session = requests_unixsocket.Session()
base_url = "http+unix:///usr/bin/app.sock"
r = session.get(base_url + "/overall")

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
assert r.status_code == 200`
```

python client.py

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 6, in <module>
    r = session.get(base_url + "/overall")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 498, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 598, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))`
```

Am i missing anything here to run it as a service?

Os: centos

Comment: if answer [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow#:~:text=Logged%20in%20as%20the%20person,previous%20acceptance%20and%20reassign%20it) could please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

base_url="http+unix://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fapp.sock"

The above line helped to solve the above issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).